# Object to Dictionary Python

Tags: python, object, dictionary, pandas, mapping

Hi guys I have a pandas column that contains objects that are dictionaries, but not recognized as dictionaries.

```
df.rowExample[0] = '[{"sold": 12, "breed": "golden"}, {"breed": "silver",  
                    "bought": 49}, {"breed": "golden", "bought": 29}]'
```

I've tried DataFrame.to_dict(df.column) and dict(df.column) but the key is just an numerical index and the value is the entire row.

Thanks!

Comment: That's just a string.  As long as your string contains only  strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None, you can convert the string using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is a string representation of a list of dictionaries. You can turn it into a list object by using `literal_eval`:

```
import ast

obj = '[{"sold": 12, "breed": "golden"}, {"breed": "silver", "bought": 49},   
       {"breed": "golden", "bought": 29}]'

obj = ast.literal_eval(obj)
```

Or somehow safer by using the `json` module:

```
import json

obj = '[{"sold": 12, "breed": "golden"}, {"breed": "silver", "bought": 49},   
       {"breed": "golden", "bought": 29}]'

obj = json.loads(obj)
```

Comment: The issue is not whether using `json.loads` is safer than using `ast.literal_eval`.  It's simply that if you have `json` you should use `json.loads` and if you have Python literals consisting of strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and `None`, you should use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Thank you DeepSpace and Steven

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if it doesnt hold a dictionary... but a string in the form of a dictionary.

try something along the lines of

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(df.rowExample[0])
```

edit: this looks like it returns a list of dictionaries... so

`for dictionary in ast.literal_eval(df.rowExample[0]):
     abetterdict = dictionary`

Comment: Thanks a lot Busterdust! I used rowExample[0] to show just one row, is there a way to do this for every row? I tried a for-loop but it's very slow

Comment: `for row in arrayOfRows:
    ast.literal_eval(row)`

it will most likely continue to be slow, you need to hit everything